# Avoid redirections on my server

Tags: curl, dns, web-scraping, python-requests, digital-ocean

When i try to fetch some non existent url on my local machine most of the time i get:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: some-non-existent-url.co
```

Sometimes however i get a 301:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://registry.co.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

In this case i am using curl, but the same happens with other tools.

In my digitalocean droplet the redirection happens every time. I can't tell between a reachable url and this fake redirection.
Is there a way to block that? In my browser when i try to go to an unreachable url i get:

```
This webpage is not available

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I know i can probably just ping the hosts, but i am interested on knowing if it is possible to disable that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: some-non-existent-url.co

Browser:

> This webpage is not available
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

This isn't some kind of 'fake' redirection, this is the DNS server telling curl on any other tool like  a browser, that the domain doesn't exist. that is, the domain does not map to any ip address.

> Is there a way to block that?

Block what precisely? please elaborate..

Comment: Browser does show it is empty, curl does not. Curl shows a 301 to a page like registry.co.com

Comment: curl by default doesn't follow redirects (atleast 301) , you need to use the -L switch using curl to follow redirects, and see what turns up.

Comment: The html i posted is what i get from my curl. However when i try to access that same url from my browser i get a not found.

Comment: then I can only guess without knowing the url, like : DNS caching by browser?? the redirect leads to a non existing site ? etc

Comment: It happens on almost any unassigned url (things like dsadbasdaidas.co). Haven't been able to reproduce this on my amazon instance. It happens from time to time on other instances on digitalocean.

Comment: I only got DNS resolving failiure with given URL. 
So fetching same URL from one server leads to 301, and from another DNS not found ? If so I would try that curl -L switch (on those 301) and check the output and headers AND I would flush those DNS caches on digitalocean.

Comment: Yeah, tried clearing the cache with no success. I ended up using http://www.statdns.com/api/ to query if the domain was assigned.